# Repair or recreate virtual drive on raid array

Tags: raid, intel

I have raid array intel srcsas18e. Today I saw that OS was shutdown and status two hdds is "foreign unconf bad". Both hdds were in one virtual drive. But I do not find this virtual drive in a config. 
I try to make unconf good. And now I can see that these hdds is foreign unconf good.
I can't create new virtual drive with these two hdds.
 How can I repair this virtual drive or create new vd?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this user manual](http://ftp.maxdata.com/MAXDATA_PLATINUM_Server/Driver_and_Utilities/Controller/Intel/RMS25_series/IR3_Software_UserGuide_r19_0.pdf) (which some idiot disabled copying text from), the "Foreign" state means that the controller sees that there is RAID configuration information on the drive but to prevent accidentally screwing up the data, it will not automatically use the drive unless you first scan the drive to examine the configuration. Apparently you will be able to either wipe the configuration (and erase all data) or import the configuration.

Most likely, the drives were marked as Bad due to failure though, I would recommend replacing them with new drives and restoring from backup.

Comment: I cant use raid web console because this virtual drive is booted for OS, and I cant erase configuration because this raid controller has two virtual drives. How can I scan disks via megaraid console, which boot after motherboard bios? Or how can  I erase only one virtual drive from two?